# get all results by pivot table id, laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

i have laravel many to many relationship
[image]

[image]

and i want to get all advertisements, with category id, example 1, in controller

whats wrong? how to get all models, by pivot table categories_id = 1?

```
    $category_details = Categories::where('slug','=', $category_slug)->first();

    $advertisements = Advertisement::with(['categories'=> function($query){
        $query->wherePivot('categories_id', $category_details->id);
    }])->get();
```

[image: and i get this error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass $category_details variable to Closure

```
$advertisements = Advertisement::with(['categories'=> function($query) use($category_details) {
        $query->wherePivot('categories_id', $category_details->id);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes use added needed functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good idea to rename the `Categories` model of yours to
a singular form and add a similar relationship to it:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function advertisements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Advertisement::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```php
$category = Category::where('slug','=', $category_slug)->firstOrFail();

return $category->advertisements()
    ->with('categories')
    ->get();
```

Or you can make it a bit fancier:

```php
return Category::where('slug','=', $category_slug)
    ->firstOr(fn() => Category::make())
    ->advertisements()
    ->with('categories')
    ->get();
```